# htaccess AuthName message adjustment

Tags: .htaccess, utf-8

How can I add the following adjustments to the AuthName message in the .htaccess file:

a) I would like to display a longer message (currently the message is cut in the middle of it)

b) How can I inset the enter (move a sentence to a new line). I tried with \n

c) I need the message to be of UTF-8.

Comment: Can you show an example of what you've got so far.

Comment: I don't think you are able to send long *messages* with an authentication request, and there is very little if any specification on how to deal with encodings or escape values in this field. In short: that's not what it's meant for and you probably simply can't do it.

Comment: It seems so but I asked the question because I want to be sure